# how can i use @custom-media in sass mixins?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

i am trying to generate `@custom-media` entries in a mixin, sourced from a sass map, but get the error that the media query is not a valid css value

eg

```
@use 'sass:map';

@mixin custom-media($breakpoints) {
  $breakpoint-names: map.keys($breakpoints);

  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoint-names {
    $media-query: null;
    $min: map.get($breakpoints, $breakpoint, width, min);
    $max: map.get($breakpoints, $breakpoint, width, max);

    @if ($min) { $min: (min-width: #{$min}); }

    @if ($max) { $max: (max-width: #{$max}); }

    @if ($min and $max) {
      $media-query: "#{$min} and #{$max}";
    }

    @else {
      $media-query: $min or $max;
    }

    @custom-media --#{breakpoint}-media-query #{$media-query};
  }
}
.root {
    @include custom-media((
        small: (
            width: (
                max: 40em,
            )
        ),
        medium: (
            width: (
                min: 40em,
                max: 80em,
            )
        ),
        large: (
            width: (
                min: 80em,
            )
        )
    ))
};
```

the error is `(max-width: 40em) is'nt a valid css value.`, despite that being exactly what i want the value to be. does sass not support the `@custom-media` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

A mixin can return only a valid CSS rules.
`@custom-media ...` It's not a valid CSS rule.

If you want customize breakpoints points, create a CSS var.

Comment: so css vars were where i originally started, but they aren't allowed in media queries, which led me to the https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media plugin, but it still requires some other mechanism to use it in media queries.  i have css variables for all my breakpoint values, but cannot seem to find a way to interpolate them into a media query

Comment: i have actually tried postcss-media-variables, postcss-custom-media, & postcss-css-variables with varying levels of failure :) perhaps media-queries are the one thing i cannot use css variables for?